# Anti derivative of modulus of z

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there an anti derivative in $\mathbb{C}$ for $ z \mapsto \left | z \right|$?

I can't seem to find a closed curve to contradict this..

Comment: What do you mean by antiderivative exactly? A function $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(A version of) [Morera's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem) says that if $f$ has an antiderivative, then it has a derivative (is holomorphic). So if you can show $|z|$ doesn't have a derivative (isn't holomorphic), it will follow it has no anti-derivative.